# Whats the meaning of CPU% for each process in top command?

Tags: 12.04, cpu, top

I was running some heavy processes inside a VM and then I used `top command` to see how much loaded the system is. Overall CPU showed 29% while CPU% for `qemu` showed 133%.

**%CPU definition from `top` man page** 
The task's share of the elapsed CPU  time  since  the  last  screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.

Can you please explain what is the meaning of %CPU for each process and why it is showing 133%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU Usage percentage in `top` is relative per core. For example, if a program was running at full capacity on each core in a quad-core machine, the program  would be reported as 400% in `top`.

In this case, `qemu` was using a sum of 133% of one core's computation power. This means that `qemu` could be using all of one core and some of another, or a little bit on each core.

[Related SU Question](https://superuser.com/a/174667)